# Angular routing without hash in url

Tags: angularjs, routes

I use angular seed template for my project. I tried to make routing without hash. I added in my app.js `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and in my index.html in head section `<base href="/">` but when I refresh a page or enter the url, result is the index of my folder. 
[image: index of view]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using express.js?

Comment: no, it's just angular-seed starter web pack https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Answer (score 0):

Your url is being processed as if it was a server resource, normally it's used a rewrite or a route that serve every url to your index.html file (or your default input).

You can do it using a different server, I sugest the `superstatic` npm package wich provides you url rewrite instead of `http-server` present on the angularjs-seed project.

```
npm install superstatic --save-dev
```

Create the file `superstatic.json` on the root of your app with the following content:

```
{
  "cleanUrls": true,
  "rewrites": [
    {"source":"/**","destination":"/app/index.html"}
  ]
}
```

And override the following line in the file `package.json`

```
"scripts": {    
    ...
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app",
    ...    
}
```

To

```
"scripts": {    
    ...
    "start": "superstatic --config superstatic.json --port 8080 --host localhost",
    ...    
}
```

And finally

```
npm start
```

Comment: still not working, I have this output

dns.js:112
    throw new TypeError('Invalid arguments: ' +
    ^

TypeError: Invalid arguments: hostname must be a string or falsey
    at Object.lookup (dns.js:112:11)
    at listenAfterLookup (net.js:1403:20)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1399:5)
    at Function.listen ...

Comment: Ops, my bad, I've forgotten to add a proper host name, changed to `"start": "superstatic --config superstatic.json --port 8080 --host localhost"`

Comment: ok it works now, but my files like css are inaccessible and i have unexpected token < in js files

Comment: I believe you can use the "cleanUrls": true," on the config file, or you can create a public path separated of your main url like `/public` or `/static` where the statics live on, but don't waste much effort on it, it's just for development, in a real server it would do in a different way.